# What is a safe alternative to .innerHTML and Jquery .append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Firefox addon got removed because of unsafe assignment to innerHTML. Replaced it with the Jquery append(), but it is also unsafe. What can I use instead?

I need to add content dynamically to the extension's DOM. Mozilla gave me this link when they took down the addon: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Safely_inserting_external_content_into_a_page
But I can not figure out from the link how to add nodes to an existing node in a safe way.

This is an example of what i'm doing now. I have several places where I append a node to another node. In this case I need to make a div for every category and add it to the node "folders"

```
var folders = $("#folders");

for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    var s = categories[i];

    var categoryFolder = $("<div>");
    categoryFolder.addClass("folder");
    categoryFolder.attr("id",s);
    categoryFolder.text(s);

    folders.append(categoryFolder);
  }
```

Comment: The relevant part of that page is this section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Safely_inserting_external_content_into_a_page#HTML_sanitization

You need to use an HTML sanitization library like DOMPurify to sanitize your HTML before you put it onto the page.

Comment: The code fragment you've shown doesn't use innerHTML. There's also nothing unsafe about jQuery's append() as it uses the standard DOM method appendChild in this case. As for `$("<div>")` it's also safe because jQuery handles this case of element tag explicitly and uses the standard DOM method createElement. So either you've shown the wrong fragment or you've got an incompetent reviewer at Mozilla, which is not really surprising, but it spells a lot of trouble for you, unfortunately.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk thanks, i'll look into it.

Comment: @wOxxOm i submitted the addon after replacing all innerHTML with append. According to Mozilla it is just as unsafe as innerHTML.

Comment: Well, what I wrote in my comment above still applies in full.